Double-clicking on TButton is giving the error : cannot find implementation of method
I have multiple TButtons on a TPageControl. The first 3 work, when I double-click on them, the IDE takes me to their procedure (ie procedure TForm3.btn1q1Click(Sender: TObject);) but it gives me this error on the rest:

cannot find implementation of method

I looked into the type code and realized that it lists all the buttons like this:
type
  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    pgc: TPageControl;
    pgclogin: TTabSheet;
    lblname: TLabel;
    lblsurnaME: TLabel;
    edtname: TEdit;
    EDTSUR: TEdit;
    btncontinue: TButton;
    pgcdiff: TTabSheet;
    rpgdiff: TRadioGroup;
    pgcsun: TTabSheet;
    btn1q1: TButton;
    btn1q2: TButton;
    btn1q3: TButton;
    btn1q4: TButton;
    btn1q5: TButton;
    btn1q6: TButton;
    btn1q7: TButton;
    btn1q8: TButton;
    btn1q9: TButton;
    mem1: TMemo;
    pgcmercury: TTabSheet;
    Btn2q6: TButton;

but only the 1st 3 (the working ones) are listed like this:
procedure btn1q1Click(Sender: TObject);
procedure btn1q2Click(Sender: TObject);
procedure btn1q3Click(Sender: TObject);

I added 2 more manually:
procedure btn1q4Click(Sender: TObject);
procedure btn1q5Click(Sender: TObject);

but it still gives that error.
What can I do? I am completely lost.

all the internet answers i got so far is to undo, i cannot do that since ive been saving and transfering the file between school and home while making the design

You manually added the declarations inside the class type in the interface section, but did you also make sure to have the corresponding definitions in the implementation section as well?

Sometimes this error can occur if the *.pas file contains strange (invisible) characters.
Perhaps you can use a text editor that can display invisible control codes and then remove them. Of course, back up the *.pas file first so that nothing else gets broken.
https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/11014-ummmm-what/?do=findComment&comment=87699

ill try that, wht should i be looking for?

i checked in emeditor, i didnt see anything concerning. do you have a special editor to see the invisible text? all i saw extra was next like symbols.

E.g. Notepad+ (https://notepad-plus-plus.org/)
View -> Show symbols -> show all characters
(Translated from German, the menu items may be slightly different in your language).
Now you can also see the control codes (CRLF, etc.) clearly.
PS: That can sometimes be the problem, but of course it can also be something else.
Good luck

oof it has ctfl everywhere

should i remove it?

it doesn't allow me to remove them

its fine ill just code (not in the button) and when i get to school just ask my teacher.

thats for the help anyways

It is possible that the buttons already have a field in the OnClick event that has been (accidentally?) deleted from the source. If this has happened you will get this error.
To check, instead of double clicking on the button, single click on the button and go to the object inspector (bottom left of the screen by default) and select the 'Events' tab. Look for the 'OnClick' event. If there is anything in there, delete it. Now your double-click should work.

